# Where is the Checksum for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, checksums

Where is the checksum for the [Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop ISO image](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso)?

I don't see it anywhere on the [download](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) page or on the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes?_ga=2.55292907.1111883171.1525008268-1998409187.1524855904) page.

The Checksums on the cd image page are for server and arm versions, but do not include a checksum for the desktop iso:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You find the checksums for Ubuntu 18.04 at [releases.ubuntu.com/bionic](http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/) (alongside the iso files).

---

Generally, you find the current released versions of Ubuntu and the Ubuntu community flavours via the link

[releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com)

Comment: No HTTPS location? :-)

Comment: @Peque, Not that I know.